# Cannot get property from ttl file

Tags: turtle-rdf

Here is a part of the ttl file.

```
@prefix rr:    <http://www.w3.org/ns/r2rml#> .
@prefix drugbank: <http://wifo5-04.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/drugbank/resource/drugbank/> .
@prefix ns5:   <http://wifo5-04.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/drugbank/resource/drugs/> .
@prefix ns8:   <http://linkeddata.finki.ukim.mk/lod/data/hifm#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix virtrdf: <http://www.openlinksw.com/schemas/virtrdf#> .
@prefix xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix hifm-ont: <http://purl.org/net/hifm/ontology#> .

<http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#976423>
        a                         hifm-ont:Drug , drugbank:drugs ;
        rdfs:label                "Amlodipine" ;
        rdfs:seeAlso              ns5:DB00381 ;
        hifm-ont:dosageForm       "Таблети" ;
        hifm-ont:id               976423 ;
        hifm-ont:manufacturer     "REPLEKFARM" ;
        hifm-ont:packaging        20 ;
        hifm-ont:refPriceNoVAT    18.1 ;
        hifm-ont:refPriceWithVAT  19.0 ;
        hifm-ont:similarTo        <http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#989088> , <http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#989096> , <http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#983756> , <http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#989118> , <http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#973424> , <http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#967483> , <http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#985759> , <http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#976385> , <http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#983691> , <http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#973432> , <http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#962392> , <http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#989061> , <http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#983721> , <http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#983713> , <http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#976393> , <http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#985732> , <http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#962384> ;
        hifm-ont:strength         "5 mg" ;
        drugbank:atcCode          "C08CA01" ;
        drugbank:brandName        "AMLODIPIN табл.20 x 5mg" ;
        drugbank:genericName      "Amlodipine" .

<http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#994995>
        a                         drugbank:drugs , hifm-ont:Drug ;
        rdfs:label                "Paroxetine" ;
        rdfs:seeAlso              ns5:DB00715 ;
        hifm-ont:dosageForm       "Таблети/Филм обложени таблети" ;
        hifm-ont:id               994995 ;
        hifm-ont:manufacturer     "PharmaS" ;
        hifm-ont:packaging        30 ;
        hifm-ont:refPriceNoVAT    443.81 ;
        hifm-ont:refPriceWithVAT  466.0 ;
        hifm-ont:similarTo        <http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#989401> , <http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#989266> , <http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#984639> , <http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#994987> , <http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#993603> , <http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#976938> , <http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#978124> , <http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#993581> , <http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#976911> , <http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#989274> ;
        hifm-ont:strength         "30 mg" ;
        drugbank:atcCode          "N06AB05" ;
        drugbank:brandName        "PAROKSETIN PharmaS филм обл.табл. 30 x 30mg" ;
        drugbank:genericName      "Paroxetine" .
```

I need to get the `brandName` property of each medicine.

First I read the file:

```
Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
InputStream in = FileManager.get().open(inputFile);
model.read(in, "", "TTL");
```

Then I form iterator with the statements:

```
StmtIterator iter = model.listStatements();
```

and then:

```
while(iter.hasNext()){
            iter.nextStatement().getProperty(DRUGBANK.brandName));
        }
```

So I get an error saying that the symbol DRUGBANK cannot be found.
How do I get the and print the `brandName` property?

Comment: Which tool are you using / where does the error come from?

Comment: I'm writing this code in Netbeans

Answer (score 0):

There are several levels of issues in the question, and I will try to address them one by one.

First, let's tackle the "symbol not found" error. From the code and development environment provided by the OP, it seems that they are using Java and Apache Jena. Since the question does not specify the type or definition of DRUGBANK in the Java code, I suspect that they may have used an example program where `DRUGBANK` is defined as a class containing related resources. However, based on the error message, it seems that the OP's code cannot successfully use the DRUGBANK class defined in the original example code.

Therefore, I have defined a Property called `drugbank_brandName`, which might fit their needs:

```java
String DRUGBANK = "http://wifo5-04.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/drugbank/resource/drugbank/"; //based on the TTL definition
Property drugbank_brandName = model.createProperty(DRUGBANK, "brandName");
```

However, the second issue is that the OP uses the getProperty() method, which is probably a misunderstanding(*). If you want to find the brand name for each medicine, I suggest modifying the code as follows:

```java
while (iter.hasNext()) {
  Statement stat = iter.nextStatement();
  if (stat.getPredicate().equals(drugbank_brandName)) {
          System.out.println(stat.getObject().asLiteral().getString());
   }
}
```

(*) Refer to Jena javadoc https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org.apache.jena.core/org/apache/jena/rdf/model/Statement.html#getProperty(org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Property) for more information.

The output result is:

```
AMLODIPIN табл.20 x 5mg
PAROKSETIN PharmaS филм обл.табл. 30 x 30mg
```

While this method can find the brand name, it is not ideal because it does not address the core concept of "medicine" in the original question. If you have any resources that also have the `drugbank:brandName` property but are not `drugbank:drugs` (medicine), they will also be fetched by this method. A better approach is to query the model based on the concept of "medicine". You can define a SPARQL query like this:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX drugbank: <http://wifo5-04.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/drugbank/resource/drugbank/>

SELECT ?label ?brandName
WHERE {
  [] a drugbank:drugs ;
      rdfs:label ?label ;
      drugbank:brandName ?brandName .
}
```

Suppose you store this query as a string in the `queryStr` variable. You can refer to the following code to query the model based on the file you read:

```java
Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryStr);
QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);
ResultSet results = qe.execSelect();
while (results.hasNext()) {
  QuerySolution solution = results.next();
  System.out.println("label = " + solution.get("label"));
  System.out.println("brandName = " + solution.get("brandName"));
}
```

`label` and `brandName` correspond to the two variables in `queryStr`:

```
SELECT ?label ?brandName
```

The output result is:

```
label = Paroxetine
brandName = PAROKSETIN PharmaS филм обл.табл. 30 x 30mg
label = Amlodipine
brandName = AMLODIPIN табл.20 x 5mg
```

To further address the original question of retrieving the `brandName` property of each medicine, using SPARQL queries allows us to work with the model as a whole and filter the results to only include statements related to drugs.

Additionally, it's worth noting that Turtle is just one of several RDF serialization formats and it's meant for human-readable representations of RDF data. When the data is ingested into a model or stored in a triplestore, it's actually converted into a set of Statements. This is similar to the following example written in Turtle:

```
<http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#976423> a hifm-ont:Drug .
<http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#976423> a drugbank:drugs .
<http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#976423> rdfs:label "Amlodipine" .
<http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#976423> rdfs:seeAlso ns5:DB00381 .
<http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#976423> hifm-ont:dosageForm "Таблети" .
<http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#976423> hifm-ont:id 976423 .
<http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#976423> hifm-ont:manufacturer "REPLEKFARM" .
<http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#976423> hifm-ont:packaging 20 .
<http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#976423> hifm-ont:refPriceNoVAT 18.1 .
<http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#976423> hifm-ont:refPriceWithVAT 19.0 .
<http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#976423> hifm-ont:similarTo <http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#989088> .
<http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#976423> hifm-ont:similarTo <http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#989096> .
<http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#976423> hifm-ont:similarTo <http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#983756> .
<http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#976423> hifm-ont:similarTo <http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#989118> .
<http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#976423> hifm-ont:similarTo <http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#973424> .
<http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#976423> hifm-ont:similarTo <http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#967483> .
<http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#976423> hifm-ont:similarTo <http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#985759> .
<http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#976423> hifm-ont:similarTo <http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#976385> .
<http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#976423> hifm-ont:similarTo <http://purl.org/net/hifm/data#983691> .
...
```

Finally, it's important to note that the solution I provided assumes that the RDF data conforms to a specific ontology or schema, in this case the `DrugBank` ontology. If the data is not structured according to a pre-defined ontology, you may need to perform more complex queries or data transformations to extract the information you need. Additionally, the solution assumes that the RDF data is stored in a local file, but you could also query data from a remote SPARQL endpoint using the same approach. You can refer to other ontology textbooks or tutorials for related concepts.